# Problems connecting ssh to GCP's compute engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh, google-compute-engine

I paused and changed the cpu to improve the performance of the compute engine (ubuntu 18.04 ).

However, after executing after setting, ssh connection is not possible at all in console, vs code.

When ssh connection is attempted, the log of the gcp serial port is as follows.

```
May 25 02:07:52 nt-ddp-jpc GCEGuestAgent[1244]: 2021-05-25T02:07:52.4696Z GCEGuestAgent Info: Adding existing user root to google-sudoers group.
May 25 02:07:52 nt-ddp-jpc GCEGuestAgent[1244]: 2021-05-25T02:07:52.4730Z GCEGuestAgent Error non_windows_accounts.go:152: gpasswd: /etc/group.1540: No space left on device# 012gpasswd: cannot lock /etc/group; try again later.#012.
```

Also, when I try ssh in vs code I get permission denied error.

What is the exact cause and resolution of the problem?

Thanks all the time for your help.

Comment: Your VM has run out of free disk space. Shut down the VM, resize the boot disk and restart.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*No space left on device* error.

To solve this issue, as John commented, you may follow this [official guide of GCP](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/working-with-persistent-disks) in order to increase space on a full boot disk. It will be possible to log in through SSH after that procedure of increase size of boot disk.

As a best practice you may [create a snapshot](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots) first, and keep in mind that increasing boot disk size and/or saving a snapshot could slightly increase the cost of your project.